# Replacing $_ substring value in powershell

Tags: powershell, replace, substring

I am trying to make further use of a wonderful piece of code I found when I tried to [replace text at a specified line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040831/replacing-a-text-at-specified-line-number-of-a-file-using-powershell).

However trying to get it to read `$_.Substring()` and then using `$_ -replace` is giving me troubles; although I get no error messages the text does not get replaced.

Here is code that does not work:

```
$content = Get-Content Z:\project\folder\subfolder\newindex2.html
$content | 
ForEach-Object { 
if ($_.ReadCount -ge 169 -and $_.ReadCount -le 171) { 
  $a = $_.Substring(40,57)
  $linked = '<a href="http://tempsite.info/folder1/folder2/' + $a + '">' + $a + '</a>'
  $_ -replace $a,$linked
} else { 
  $_ 
} 
} | 
Set-Content Z:\project\folder\subfolder\newindex2.html
```

The whole point is to make the content of a cell in a html table column link to a file on a webserver with the same name as what's in the cell.

I didn't have any luck trying my hand at regex trying to match the filenames, but since I managed to make it so the text that's to be replaced always ends up at the same position, I figured I'd try positional replacement instead.
The text that is to be replaced is always 57 characters long and always starts at position 40.

I looked at the variables getting set, and everything gets set correctly, except that

```
$_ -replace $a,$linked
```

does not replace anything.
Instead, the whole file just gets written anew with nothing changed. Can anyone please point to what I am missing and/or point to how to reach the result more easily? Maybe I'm using Substring wrong and should be using something else?

Comment: What does `$a` look like? Does it have special regex charaters in the string. That would prevent the match you are looking for. I would like to see what those 3 lines look like from a sample file first.

Comment: Also, If you already know what you are replacing you dont even need regex at all. I would need to see $a I think before I could answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first item in the right-hand argument of `-replace` is a regex pattern, so depending on what the substring contains, some of the characters might be regex control characters.

You can either escape it:

```
$_ -replace $([regex]::Escape($a)),$linked
```

Or use the `String.Replace()` method, which does not use regex:

```
$_.Replace($a,$linked)
```

Finally, as @Matt points out, you might want to avoid the find-and-replace approach altogether, since you already know at which character indices you need to insert your new value:

```
$_.Remove(40,57).Insert(40,$linked)
```

Comment: This is not right. There is a readcount property. Use GM and you will see. After reading it seems clear what he is doing. His replace is what is question

Comment: This last edit after @Matt made their point resolved the issue. Many thanks! :)